# How to get a variable out of document.ready in the same file

Tags: jquery

```
var shiny;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').keypress( function(e){
   if(e.which == 13) {
    shiny = "peridots"
  }
})
```

after assigning `shiny = "peridots"`, I want to make this variable available outside of the `document.ready` within the same file.

edit: I want to be able to access it like this:

```
var motion = shiny;
```

Comment: Since the variable is declared outside it is already available globally. Please explain issue in more detail. What are you trying to do with the variable?

Comment: var shiny is already declared outside, it would be available globally automatically

Comment: It is already avaliable outside of the document.ready because you defined it outside of the document.ready

Comment: I tried to console.log shiny outside the document.ready and I get undefined.

Comment: Well it will be undefined until that event occurs. This sounds like an XY-Problem. Provide details of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: the value would not be visible until the keypress event is triggered and the key value = 13, which is enter key.

Comment: Yes I presssed kepress but after that I want the var to set.

Comment: `motion` won't change if `shiny` does. Primitives have no inheritance. You aren't explaining problem with enough detail

Comment: Is that not what it's doing already with the code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

`"shiny"` is already public to everything else since you initialized `"shiny"` outside of document.ready. If you tried `console.log(shiny)` and you get `undefined`, that means the `document` hasn't fully loaded yet or `$('.box').keypress()` wasn't hit yet. If you have a `debugger` like Visual Studios, and put a `breakpoint` on the line `shiny = "peridots"` and it is not hit, that means shiny has not been defined yet.

Comment: semi colon is irrelevant. Not required in non minified javascript although it is best practice to use them